# Binary File Support

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I need to log raw data off of sensors. I need features such as every 15 minutes, create a new log file or after the file reaches a certain size, create new file.

I'd like to leverage an existing framework such as log4net but it appears there isn't much out there on how to, or if it will support, adding a custom logger to log binary data. Has anyone done this or have come across an implementation of something similar that matches my needs as described throughout this post?

I should add that we are looking at ~300GB a day of data here. We are saving this data for the ability of post analysis and algorithm tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage log4net or any other text-logging tool by taking your `byte[]` data and converting it to plain text using [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can convert it back later using [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: That would result in a much larger file than the initial binary though .

Comment: @MQS Base64 uses 8 bits (an ASCII character) to store 6 bits of data (64 = 2^6). So your data becomes 33% larger when it's Base64-encoded. It's up to you whether that's too much, but I would expect it should be fine.

Comment: Well, we are logging a min of 300GB a day, so 33% of that is a lot :)

Comment: @MQS You might want to add that to your question. 0.3 TB/day sounds like a lot of "logging." :) Consider that logging frameworks typically aren't engineered for that use case. When you said "raw data off of sensors" I assumed that meant a small binary payload that needed to be logged with the rest of your non-binary data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I apologize that was missing.

We are saving this data for post analysis.

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` class implemented. It does exactly what you expect it to do...it deals with raw bytes to/from a file (or any `Stream` for that matter). So all you have to do, is create a simple file format for yourself then read data out of it.

You can, of course, convert the binary data to other formats (like string) then use any serialization scheme you like (JSON, XML, etc. you name it). But since you're dealing with binary data, converting them to other formats sounds may not be the most elegant solution.

Comment: I realize this, but what I was looking for, and maybe i wasn't very clear, were the mechanisms of log rollovers based on size and/or time that you get with a framework like log4net.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any logging frameworks that does exactly that. Microsoft has its Enterprise Library for .NET which includes many useful design patterns, logging is one of them. You might wanna take a look.

Comment: Ok. I appreciate your help.